# Minimising one parameter at a time not simultaneously

Tags: optimization

I have a script that minimises a function

```
#Imports
import os
from scipy.optimize import minimize

initial_guess = [-20.0,4.0]
bounds_num = [(-21, -15),(2,6)]


def run_topspin(params):
    p, p_2 = params   

### running a command in another program

    PI_file_path = r'C:\users\...\desktop\Peak_Intensities.txt'
    with open(PI_file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            x = float(line.strip())

    x = 1/(x**0.001)

    return x



result = minimize(run_topspin, initial_guess, method='Powell', bounds=bounds_num, options={'xtol': 0.3, 'ftol':0.3})
```

This is a paired down version but i have two parameters going in to output a single x.

However when i run this it fixes p_2 and optimises p. once done it optimises p_2 and then finishes. I need it to optimise both at the same time not one then the other.

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgxU9.png)
In this example pi = x